# Howto parse xml-tags with prefixes using jersey and jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, xml-namespaces, tagprefix

I'm trying to parse XML-data which has prefixes.

I'm using Java: Jersey with Jaxb -librarys.

How to do I tell Annanotation: @XmlRootElement-to,
that my xml has prefixes?

My root element is like `<soapenv:Envelope>`.

should my do Annotation like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="soapenv:Envelope") // I'll get HTTP 400 Bad request
```

or

```
@XmlRootElement(name="/soapenv:Envelope") // I'll get HTTP 400 Bad request
```

or

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Envelope" namespace"soapenv:") // Don't remeber what I get, propably HTTP 400
```

or

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Envelope" ) //With this I'll get NullPointerException
```

XML-code that I need to parse:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns="http://someurl-1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <customerID>CID1</customerID>
        <companyName>some company name</companyName>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My java-class looks like this:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "ns:response") // something is wrong
public class MyXMLClass {
    @XmlElement(name = "soapenv:Body" )
    public Body body;
}
```

I'd tried to make my easier xml-code, without prefixes and I got my code to work,
but I need to work it with prefixes.

I tried to search from net also, it seems that this topic has very little info.
"
I also tried to put `@XmlElement` before, or after the `@XmlRootElement`, to tell what is actual element, but already javac told me it's not possible to use it that way:

```
@XmlElement(name = "soapenv:Envelope" )
@XmlRootElement
public class MyXMLClass {
...
```

So anyway: **How to parse xml-tags with prefixes?**

Comment: First, you need to learn what XML *namespaces* are, and how they work. Second, you need to use `@XmlRootElement(name="Envelope", namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")`, though it might be better to specify the namespace at the package level.

Comment: Thanks advise, for that right syntax, how it goes.

That way I have actually had it in first place, but I thought there were some mistake, cause I got NullPointerException when I Initialized `Body body` in Main class.